# Flutter/Dart Isolate and Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter/Dart code. This dart code consists of a UI and a provider. In the provider part, I have a code like this: since the function in it is "static", I cannot use "notifyListeners()", which is the function that I can update the value. Everything else works properly, the problem comes when it comes to updating. In short, I can't use Isolate class and notifyListeners() together. Is there a solution for this?

I have tried calling another functions that can update. And tried sending it in sendPort. However, it does not update UI either.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please [edit] your question to include a [mre] with code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Use a Callback Function**: pass a callback function to your static function

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static void myStaticFunction(Function() notifyListeners) {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And when calling `myStaticFunction`:

```
MyProvider.myStaticFunction(() {
  Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).notifyListeners();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!